# Evaluating then extracting rows of a matrix into a new matrix

Tags: matlab

I could not find how to do the following in MATLAB, any help is appreciated:

- I have a matrix X of dimension (mxn) and I want to find which rows have the first element greater than the remaining elements of the same row. And then put the rows that satisfy this in a new matrix Y.

Example:
If X is

```
2  0  1
3  8  6
7  2  5
```

Y would be

```
2  0  1
7  2  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `bsxfun` and `all`:

```
X = [
    2  0  1
    3  8  6
    7  2  5];

Y = X( all(bsxfun(@gt, X(:,1), X(:,2:end)),2), :)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function works on matrices like this:

> If A is a matrix, max(A) treats the columns of A as vectors, returning
>   a row vector containing the maximum element from each column.

That means you will need to work with the transpose of x.

```
x = [2 0 1;
     3 8 6; 
     7 2 5];
xt = x';
[maxVal, maxIdx] = max(xt);
```

Now, if your `maxIdx` value is 1, that means the first value is the greatest.

```
y = x(maxIdx == 1, :);
```

will give you your new matrix.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis Thanks, but yours is much shorter :)